# Can't instantiate class.Tabs; no empty constructor, actionBar.Tab's in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity

I have implemented a FragmentTabHost for a new tab-system. But soon realized I aswell need actionBars and tabListener support. My problem is the following: I have managed the implementation for FragmentTabHost without **actionBar** and **tabListener**(see code further below). But with FragmentActivity(using actionBars / implementing tabListener) I am not able to get the code working. What am I missing …?

***The code I am trying with:***

```
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Tabs extends FragmentActivity {

    protected static final String TAG = Tabs.class.toString();

    private boolean haveShownStartDialog = false;

    protected ISettingsDataProvider settings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

        bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
                .setText("Search")
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<LandingSearch>(
                        this, "search", LandingSearch.class)));

        bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
                .setText("Bookmark")
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<LandingBookmark>(
                        this, "bookmark", LandingBookmark.class)));

        bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
                .setText("History")
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<LandingHistory>(
                        this, "search", LandingHistory.class)));

        bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
                .setText("Forum")
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<LandingForum>(
                        this, "search", LandingForum.class)));
    }


    public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
        private final String mTag;
        private final Class<T> mClass;
        private final Bundle mArgs;
        private Fragment mFragment;
        public TabListener(FragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
            this(activity, tag, clz, null);
        }


        public TabListener(FragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz, Bundle args) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mTag = tag;
            mClass = clz;
            mArgs = args;
            // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
            // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
            // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
            mFragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
            if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isDetached()) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(mFragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // Since ActionBar.TabListener needs android.app.FragmentTransaction, define the method signature with it, but don't use it
            // Instead use the support fragment manager
            FragmentTransaction fft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            if (mFragment == null) {
                mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs);
                fft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
            } else {
                fft.attach(mFragment);
            }

            // Don't forget to call commit, as we are not using FragmentTransaction passed by ActionBar.
            fft.commit();
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            FragmentTransaction fft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            if (mFragment != null) {
                fft.detach(mFragment);
            }

            fft.commit();
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

**Example of one tab-class..**

```
public class LandingSearch extends Fragment
{
    protected static final String TAG = LandingSearch.class.toString();

    …….

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.landing_search, container, false);
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState, v);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        initList(v);
code continues….
```

**The new null pointer error:**

```
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com./com.Tabs}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at com.Tabs.onCreate(Tabs.java:42)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
05-13 11:57:41.322: E/AndroidRuntime(18118):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Do you have a public empty constructor in `LandingForum.class` ? (if not add it and try again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a paramterized `Tabs` constructor, the default constructor is not available to the system to create an instance of it. To overcome this issue, you need to explicitly define a default constructor.

But there is another issue with the current implementation:

```
ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.LabelSearchTabTitle).setTabListener((ActionBar.TabListener)new Tabs(this, LandingSearch.class, TAG ));
```

The current approach results in creating a instance of Activity for each tab added. Instead current instance i.e. `this` need to be passed to `setTabListener`, which is not possible.

**Solution** : 
The cleaner approach would be instead of `Tabs` implementing `ActionBar.TabListener`, define a inner class in `Tabs` which will implement  `ActionBar.TabListener` and explicitly set an instance of it on each tab that will be created.

Here is the code:

```
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    protected static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.toString();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

        bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
                .setText("Search")
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<LandingSearch>(
                        this, "search", LandingSearch.class)));

        bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
                .setText("Book")
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<LandingBook>(
                        this, "book", LandingBook.class)));
    }


    public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
        private final String mTag;
        private final Class<T> mClass;
        private final Bundle mArgs;
        private Fragment mFragment;
        public TabListener(FragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
            this(activity, tag, clz, null);
        }


        public TabListener(FragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz, Bundle args) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mTag = tag;
            mClass = clz;
            mArgs = args;
            // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
            // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
            // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
            mFragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
            if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isDetached()) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(mFragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // Since ActionBar.TabListener needs android.app.FragmentTransaction, define the method signature with it, but don't use it
            // Instead use the support fragment manager
            FragmentTransaction fft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            if (mFragment == null) {
                mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs);
                fft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
            } else {
                fft.attach(mFragment);
            }

            // Don't forget to call commit, as we are not using FragmentTransaction passed by ActionBar.
            fft.commit();
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            FragmentTransaction fft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            if (mFragment != null) {
                fft.detach(mFragment);
            }

            fft.commit();
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    public static class LandingSearch extends Fragment
    {
        protected static final String TAG = LandingSearch.class.toString();

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.landing_search, container, false);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Other code.

            return v;
        }
    }

    public static class LandingBook extends Fragment
    {
        protected static final String TAG = LandingBook.class.toString();

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.landing_book, container, false);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Other code

            return v;
        }
    }

}
```

Look at this [Android example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.java).

Comment: Thx for you answer! Check my question below!

Comment: @user1293618 I've updated my answer. You need to instantiate / attach the Fragment in onTabSelected method and detach the Fragment in onTabUnselected method.

Comment: @user1293618 I hope you have imported android.support.v4.app.Fragment in both Tabs and LandingSearch. You also need to replace getFragmentManager with getSupportFragmentManager.

Comment: Thanx for pointing that out, at least it moved me one step closer. I don't get any warnings in the code any longer, but it results in a null pointer exception instead when running it :/ Not sure why, the code and error you can find above in my edited version of your post..

Comment: @user1293618 can u post the logcat? especially the location where null pointer exception is thrown.

Comment: Check my edited version of my original post! / thanx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52586/discussion-between-manish-mulimani-and-user1293618)

Comment: @user1293618 Where u able to debug the issue?

Comment: I got it work with actionBarSherlock instead, so I have solved the issue. Thx for your help Manish. I will accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see this specific problem in your code but if you created the actionbar using the Eclipse wizard your problem may be solved by this: [How can we retain a simple State Array across Configuration changes using Headless Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362327/how-can-we-retain-a-simple-state-array-across-configuration-changes-using-headle)